# Get Request from Spring Boot to another Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, get-request

I need to create a communication between two Spring Servers. Both of the servers works, I have tested them with "Postman". First server:
[image]

And this is the second server:

[image]

Server1: (that must performe the get request)

This is the "CheckService":

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class CheckService {

    private CheckModel checkModel;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public CheckService(){}
    private WebClient webClient;

    public CheckService(CheckModel checkModel){
        this.checkModel = checkModel;
        this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:1200/api").build();
    }
    

    public String CheckDataset(){
        try {

            CheckModel checkModel1 = new CheckModel();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("Alex");
            list.add("check");

            checkModel1.setChecking(list);

            return webClient.get()
                    .uri("/Check")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .block();
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
   }
}
```

This is the "CheckModel" class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CheckModel {
    protected List<String> checking;
    public CheckModel(){}

}
```

Server2: (server that must response to the get request)

The "RequestController" class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = {"/api"})
public class RequestsController {

    private final HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> DatasetMaps = ProcessingApplication.DatasetMaps;

    @GetMapping(path = {"Check"})
    public String Check(@RequestBody CheckModel checkModel){
        GetCheck getCheck = new GetCheck(this.DatasetMaps);
        return getCheck.GetCheckDatasetMethod(checkModel.checking);
    }
  }
}
```

The "CheckModel" class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CheckModel {
    protected List<String> checking;
    public CheckModel(){}
}
```

This is the security of the second server:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ServerSecurity{

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
        httpSecurity.httpBasic();

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

The error that the First server receive is: 401 Unauthorized.
I do not know if the "WebClient" is the correct way of doing it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: WebClient is fine but you need to add authentication. It says 401 which means that you didn't authenticate with server2

Comment: Maybe is something to do with CORS, you can try to add a bean to allow all connections:

`@Bean
    CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
        final CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("*");

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }`

Comment: Remove auth if you don't want to use. disable security by adding this line to properties file security.ignored=/**

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I tried to disable the security, but is not working.

Comment: @grekier I knew it is kind of a authenticate error, but I did not how to solve it

Comment: @Slimu I am trying to do what you suggested, but I have this error: java: incompatible types: org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource cannot be converted to org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource

Comment: My example was for Spring WebFlux endpoints, for non-reactive you can read here https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: In the end I figure it out it was a silly mistake with the URI